# Decoding ARM instruction from GDB

Tags: c, debugging, assembly, arm, arm64

I want to understand/decode the ARM instructions on my aarch64 device.

I have the following code written in C language:

```
void test_function(int a, int b, int c, int d) {
  int flag;
  char buffer[10];

  flag = 31337;
  buffer[0] = 'A';
}

int main() {
  test_function(1, 2, 3, 4);
}
```

`gcc -g stack_example.c` and `gdb -q ./a.out` yields the following assembly:

```
(gdb) disass main
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x00000000000016d4 <+0>:     stp     x29, x30, [sp, #-16]!
   0x00000000000016d8 <+4>:     mov     x29, sp
   0x00000000000016dc <+8>:     mov     w0, #0x1                        // #1
   0x00000000000016e0 <+12>:    mov     w1, #0x2                        // #2
   0x00000000000016e4 <+16>:    mov     w2, #0x3                        // #3
   0x00000000000016e8 <+20>:    mov     w3, #0x4                        // #4
   0x00000000000016ec <+24>:    bl      0x16a8 <test_function>
   0x00000000000016f0 <+28>:    mov     w0, wzr
   0x00000000000016f4 <+32>:    ldp     x29, x30, [sp], #16
   0x00000000000016f8 <+36>:    ret
End of assembler dump.
(gdb) disass test_function
Dump of assembler code for function test_function:
   0x00000000000016a8 <+0>:     sub     sp, sp, #0x20
   0x00000000000016ac <+4>:     str     w0, [sp, #28]
   0x00000000000016b0 <+8>:     str     w1, [sp, #24]
   0x00000000000016b4 <+12>:    str     w2, [sp, #20]
   0x00000000000016b8 <+16>:    str     w3, [sp, #16]
   0x00000000000016bc <+20>:    mov     w8, #0x7a69                     // #31337
   0x00000000000016c0 <+24>:    str     w8, [sp, #12]
   0x00000000000016c4 <+28>:    mov     w8, #0x41                       // #65
   0x00000000000016c8 <+32>:    strb    w8, [sp, #2]
   0x00000000000016cc <+36>:    add     sp, sp, #0x20
   0x00000000000016d0 <+40>:    ret
End of assembler dump.
```

When I now do `break 10`, `break test_function`, `run` and `disass main` i get

```
(gdb) disass main
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x00000055907a86d4 <+0>:     stp     x29, x30, [sp, #-16]!
   0x00000055907a86d8 <+4>:     mov     x29, sp
   0x00000055907a86dc <+8>:     mov     w0, #0x1                        // #1
   0x00000055907a86e0 <+12>:    mov     w1, #0x2                        // #2
   0x00000055907a86e4 <+16>:    mov     w2, #0x3                        // #3
   0x00000055907a86e8 <+20>:    mov     w3, #0x4                        // #4
=> 0x00000055907a86ec <+24>:    bl      0x55907a86a8 <test_function>
   0x00000055907a86f0 <+28>:    mov     w0, wzr
   0x00000055907a86f4 <+32>:    ldp     x29, x30, [sp], #16
   0x00000055907a86f8 <+36>:    ret
End of assembler dump.
```

Now according to [Arm Architecture Reference Manual Armv8, for A-profile architecture, page 934](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0487/gb/) the BL instruction starts with 100101 followed by a 26bit immediate value.

Examining the memory at the position of the program counter with yields

```
(gdb) x/16b 0x55907a86ec
0x55907a86ec <main+24>: 11101111        11111111        11111111        10010111        11100000        00000011        00011111        00101010
0x55907a86f4 <main+32>: 11111101        01111011        11000001        10101000        11000000        00000011        01011111        11010110
```

I think, the instruction starts in the fourth byte, but i am not sure. I tried to reconstruct the adress 0x55907a86a8, but wasn't able. Could anyone please help?

Comment: The address is given relative to the current address.  The instruction is encoded in little endian.  Apply these two hints and you should be able to find the solution.

Comment: As fuz said, the offset is little endian so it's `11 11111111 11111111 11101111` which is -17 decimal and is shifted by 2. So, you have `55907a86ec - (17 << 2) = 0x55907a86a8`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AArch64 instructions are encoded little-endian, so if you dump the code one byte at a time, each 4-byte word will have the bytes in reverse order.  Therefore, from the output you have, you'll have to take the first 4 bytes, reverse their order (but do not reverse the bits within the bytes), and concatenate them.  (You can get the debugger to do it for you by doing `x/tw 0x55907a86ec` instead.)  This gives:

```
10010111111111111111111111101111
```

Indeed the highest 6 bits are the opcode `100101`.  The immediate is `11111111111111111111101111`.  This is a negative number in two's-complement (recall that the immediate is sign-extended), with value `-17` or `-0x11`.  This number is multiplied by 4 (shift left two bits), yielding `-0x44` and added to the address of the `bl` instruction itself to find the branch target.  And indeed `0x00000055907a86ec - 0x44 = 0x55907a86a8`, which is the address the debugger showed you, and would be the address of the first instruction of `test_function`.

Note that [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) was done when you began running the program, which is why the disassembly shows different addresses before and after `run`.  If you did `disassemble test_function` after `run`, you should see it start at `0x55907a86a8`.  Nonetheless, if you look at the pre-ASLR disassembly, you'll notice that the relative displacement between the address of the `bl test_function` instruction (`0x16ec`) and the address of `test_function` itself (`0x16a8`) is the same `-0x44`.  (Indeed ASLR is done in page units, so the low 12 bits are unchanged by it.)

Comment: Thanks! I could never find out about the left-shift by myself. I could only find that the offset of the two adresses 0x...EC - 0x...A8 = 0x44 = 68 and -68=1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1011 1100 which is indeed the immediate left-shifted two times..  Why is it not coded as -68, but -17? This seems like magic to me and i don't understand why it is this way and one has to first left-shift twice but it seems to works. No hint for this in the reference.

Comment: @jahro_me: The Architecture Reference Manual does say (indirectly) that the shift occurs: the decode shows `imm26:'00'` which is to say "tack on two zero bits", equivalent to a left shift.  And under Assembler Symbols it says "Its offset from the address of this instruction,
in the range +/-128MB, is encoded as `imm26` times 4."  The reason is simply that it gains two useful bits.  AArch64 instructions are always aligned to 4 bytes, so if the displacement were encoded in the instruction without a shift, the low 2 bits would always be zero and effectively wasted. [...]

Comment: @jahro_me: And in that case, the biggest displacement you could get would be 2^26 bytes = +/- 32 MB.  With the shift, those bits aren't wasted and you can get displacement up to +/- 128 MB, much better for a big program.  In essence, the two low bits can be taken as implicitly zero instead of being actually encoded in the instruction.

Comment: Excellent. Yes, i have read about the bits(64) offset = SignExtend(imm26:'00', 64); Makes total sense. I should read more carefully. Best regards and thanks for your excellent answer!